# printf unaligned output

Tags: c, printf, hashtable

In this line `printf("%ld,%ld,%s,%s\n", i, j,   songtitle, interpreter);`
`printf()` gives me an unaligned output, I cannot figure out why.
e.g:

```
1. 0,0,2
2.     2
3. 1    0     ----    ----
4. 2    0     ----    ----
```

here is my print function:

```
void print_hash(hashcontainer_t *hashcontainer)
{   long i ,j;
    if(hashcontainer == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Hashtable is Empty!\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<hashcontainer->hashsize;i++)
    {
        if(hashcontainer->hasharrays[i].num_entries == 0)
        {
            printf("%ld     0       ----        ----\n",i);
        }
        else
        {
            for(j=0;j<hashcontainer->hasharrays[i].num_entries;j++)
            {
            char *songtitle = hashcontainer->hasharrays[i].entries[j].songtitle;
          char *interpreter = hashcontainer->hasharrays[i].entrie[j].interpreter;
          printf("%ld,%ld,%s,%s\n", i, j,   songtitle, interpreter);
            }    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Here is my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct hashentry_s
{
    char songtitle[256], interpreter[256];
} hashentry_t;

typedef struct hasharray_s
{
    hashentry_t *entries;
    long num_entries;
} hasharray_t;

typedef struct hashcontainer_s
{
    hasharray_t *hasharrays;
    long hashsize;
} hashcontainer_t;


long hash_key(char songtitle[], char interpreter[], long hash_max)
{
    unsigned long index = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(songtitle); ++i)
        index = 64 * index + (long)(songtitle[i]);
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(interpreter); ++i)
        index = 64 * index + (long)(interpreter[i]);
    return index % hash_max;
}

hashcontainer_t * create_hash (long hashsize )
{
    hashcontainer_t *container=0;
    container = calloc(1,sizeof(hashcontainer_t));
    if(container == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error allocating Memory!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    container->hasharrays = calloc(hashsize,sizeof(hasharray_t));
    if(container->hasharrays == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error Allocating Memory!/n");
        free(container);
        return 0;
    }
    container->hashsize = hashsize;
    return container;
}

void delete_hash ( hashcontainer_t * hashcontainer )
{
    long i;
    if(hashcontainer == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Hashtable is Empty!/n");
        return;
    }
    if(hashcontainer->hasharrays == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Hasharrays not Allocated or Empty!/n");
        free(hashcontainer);
        return;
    }
    for(i=0;i<hashcontainer->hashsize;i++)
            free(hashcontainer->hasharrays[i].entries);
    hashcontainer->hashsize = 0;
    hashcontainer =0;
    free(hashcontainer->hasharrays);
    free(hashcontainer);
}


void insert_entry(hashcontainer_t *hashcontainer, char songtitle[], char interpreter[])
{
    long key =0,position;
    if(hashcontainer == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Memory is not Allocated!\n");
        return;
    }
    key = hash_key(songtitle,interpreter,hashcontainer->hashsize);
    position = hashcontainer->hasharrays[key].num_entries;
    hashcontainer->hasharrays[key].entries = realloc(hashcontainer->hasharrays[key].entries,(position+1)* sizeof(hashentry_t));
   if(hashcontainer->hasharrays[key].entries == 0)
   {
       fprintf(stderr,"Error Allocating New size\n");
       return;
   }
   strcpy(hashcontainer->hasharrays[key].entries[position].songtitle,songtitle);
   strcpy(hashcontainer->hasharrays[key].entries[position].interpreter,interpreter);
   hashcontainer->hasharrays[key].num_entries++;
}


void print_hash(hashcontainer_t *hashcontainer)
{   long i ,j;
    if(hashcontainer == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Hashtable is Empty!\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<hashcontainer->hashsize;i++)
    {
        if(hashcontainer->hasharrays[i].num_entries == 0)
        {
            printf("%ld     0       ----        ----\n",i);
        }
        else
        {
        for(j=0;j<hashcontainer->hasharrays[i].num_entries;j++)
        {
            char *songtitle = hashcontainer->hasharrays[i].entries[j].songtitle;
            char *interpreter = hashcontainer->hasharrays[i].entries[j].interpreter;
            printf("%ld,%ld,%s,%s\n", i, j, songtitle, interpreter);
        }

        }    
    }    
}    

hashentry_t * search_entry ( hashcontainer_t * hashcontainer ,char songtitle [], char interpreter [])
{
    long i ,key;
    if(hashcontainer == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"hashcontainer not allocated!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    key = hash_key(songtitle,interpreter,hashcontainer->hashsize);
    for(i=0;i<hashcontainer->hashsize;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(hashcontainer->hasharrays[key].entries[i].songtitle,songtitle)==0 && strcmp(hashcontainer->hasharrays[key].entri interpreter,interpreter)==0)
            return &hashcontainer->hasharrays[key].entries[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    hashcontainer_t *container=0;
    hashentry_t *found=0;
    char c;
    char songtitle[256],interpreter[256];
    long hashsize;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("1- Creat Hash\n");
        printf("2- Insert Hash\n");
        printf("3- Print Hash\n");
        printf("4- Delete Hash\n");
        printf("5- Search Entry\n");
        scanf("%c",&c);
        getchar();
        switch (c)
        {
        case '1':
            printf("Please Insert the size of your hash:   ");
            scanf("%ld",&hashsize);
            getchar();
            printf("\n");
            container = create_hash(hashsize);
            break;
        case '2':
            printf("Please Insert a Songtitle:   ");
            fgets(songtitle,256,stdin);
            printf("\n");
            printf("Please Insert an Interpreter:   ");
            fgets(interpreter,256,stdin);
            printf("\n");
            insert_entry(container,songtitle,interpreter);
            break;
        case '3':
            printf("\n");
            print_hash(container);
            break;
        case '4':
            delete_hash(container);
            break;
        case '5':
            printf("Please Insert the Songtitle that you want to search for:   ");
            fgets(songtitle,256,stdin);
            printf("\n");
            printf("Please Insert the Interpreter:   ");
            fgets(interpreter,256,stdin);
            printf("\n");
            found = search_entry(container,songtitle,interpreter);
            if(found == 0)
                printf("No elements foundn\n");
            else
                printf("Found at %p\n",found);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: first `align` [read : format] your code sample, please.

Comment: Are you using a fixed size font in your output ?

Comment: yes , the size is fixed

Comment: What do you mean by "*Unaligned output*"? Please provide expected output.

Comment: I mean that the output should be on the same raw , since I am not using any sequences in between the variables.

Comment: If you get the output on 2 rows, then either your data contains embedded line breaks or are on the same line but appear to be on separate lines because they are wider than  the window. Another possibility is that your strings aren't null terminated, causing undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your question what do you mean by "*aligned*" but my understanding you want your data to be aligned into columns like this:

```
  1, 100,  hello world,   7
100, 100,           no, 100
```

You may see it on this simple example:

```
printf("%d,%d,%s,%s\n", 1, 10, "short", "short");
printf("%d,%d,%s,%s\n", 1, 100, "long long string", "short");
```

Producing:

```
1,10,short,short
1,100,long long string,short
```

When you take a look on [`printf()` documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) supported format is:

> `%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier`

Having `0` flag (in case that you want print fixed width numbers "*zero-filled*" `10 => 0010`).

> `0`   Left-pads the number with zeroes (0) instead of spaces when padding is specified (see width sub-specifier).

And `width` parameter:

> Minimum number of characters to be printed. If the value to be printed is shorter than this number, the result is padded with blank spaces. The value is not truncated even if the result is larger.

So extending my example to:

```
printf("%4d,%4d,%20s,%20s\n", 1, 10, "short", "short");
printf("%4d,%4d,%20s,%20s\n", 1, 100, "long long string", "short");
```

Will produce:

```
   1,  10,               short,               short
   1, 100,    long long string,               short
^^^^ ^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   4    4                   20                   20
```

You just have to decide the column widths upfront (and any data longer than your column will break that row).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do;

`printf ("%ld\t0\t----\t----\n", i)`

`\t`simply creates a tab. Mutiples of this can increase the spacing.